# Efficient way to import libraries for class methods, in Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods, import

What is the python and efficient way of importing libraries that are used throughout class's methods.

Module-level import is:

```
from numpy import exp

class A:
    def calc1(self): return exp(1)
    def calc2(self): return exp(1)
```

Method-level import is cleaner, but I'm not sure if library is cached or imported every time a method is called:

```
class B:
    def calc1(self):
        from numpy import exp
        return exp(1)

    def calc2(self):
        from numpy import exp
        return exp(1)
```

Finally, is there some class-level import as following?

```
class C:
    from numpy import exp
    def calc1(self): return exp(1)
    def calc2(self): return exp(1)

C().calc1()   # NameError: name 'exp' is not defined
```

Comment: Module level imports are often cleaner than method level imports - you can easily see everything that's being imported in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do class-level import, but you'll have to then call it as `self.exp` instead of just `exp`, since the imported name will be a class variable.  But I think in general module-level import is simpler and should be preferred unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise (e.g., circular imports or imports that won't always be available).